# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'path.pieceNum_')

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm having an issue that I don't know how to solve. I'm using Firebase/database to store data for a Chat page that I'm building.

The chat info that is going to the process is:

```
    const chatData = {
      idService: idService,
      ServiceName: name,
      users: [idUserOwner,uid],
      messageText: messageText,
  };
```

I build this code to be able to register the chat information into "chats" but also, I want to create a  collection called userCharts that for each iduser can capture the chats where the user is included.

```
import { child, getDatabase, push, ref } from "firebase/database";
import {db} from "../../utils"


export const createChat = async (uid,chatData) => {

    const newChatData = {
        ...chatData,
        createdBy: uid,
        updatedBy: uid,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
    };
    const newChat = await push(child(db, 'chats'), newChatData);

    const chatUsers = newChatData.users;
    for (let i = 0; i < chatUsers.length; i++) {
        const userId = chatUsers[i];
        await push(child(db, `userChats/${userId}`), newChat.key);
    }

    return newChat.key;
}
```

trying to have this like end result:[image]

error: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'path.pieceNum_')]

Comment: That first error likely comes from this line: `await setDoc(doc(db,`userChats/${userId}`), newChat.id);`. What do you expect this line to accomplish?

Comment: Note that your first snippet uses the API for Cloud Firestore, but the screenshot and second code snippet are for the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one doesn't work on the other. I recommend picking one and *only* working with (and asking about) that one.

Comment: You are totally right, I was confused using firestore running comands for database. Thanks for alert of the issue! You are the best.

Comment: There's a lot going on in the code, but so I recommend debugging it locally. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?